# Zend Framework Validator message error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have validator error translator connected with my Form

```
  class My_Lib_Forms_Form extends Zend_Form {

    public function init()

   {
       parent::init();

       $translator = new Zend_Translate('array', APPLICATION_PATH . '/languages/errors.php');

       // Задаем объект переводчика для формы
       $this->setTranslator($translator);    
   }
}
```

Here is validator error translator code:

```
<?php
return $errors = array(
   Zend_Validate_Alnum::STRING_EMPTY => "Поле не может быть пустым",
   Zend_Validate_Date::INVALID_DATE => 'Значение не соответствует формату год-месяц-день',
   Zend_Validate_Date::INVALID => 'Неверная дата',
   Zend_Validate_Date::FALSEFORMAT => 'Значение не соответствует указанному формату',
   Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => "asdasd",
   Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => "Не верный формат адреса электронной почты. Введите почту в формате local-part@hostname",
   Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME => "'%hostname%' не верный домен для адреса электронной почты '%value%'",
   Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD => "'%hostname%' не имеет MX-записи об адресе электронной почты '%value%'",
   Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM => "'%localPart%' не соответствует формату dot-atom",
   Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::QUOTED_STRING => "'%localPart%' не соответствует формату quoted-string",
   Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => "'%localPart%' не верное имя для адреса электронной почты '%value%'",
   Zend_Validate_Int::NOT_INT => 'Значение не является целочисленным значением',
   Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Поле не может быть пустым',
   Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT => 'Длина введённого значения меньше чем %min% символов',
   Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG => 'Длина введённого значения больше чем %max% символов',
   My_Lib_Validate_EqualInputs::NOT_EQUAL => 'Пароли не совпадают',
   My_Lib_Validate_Password::INVALID => 'Не верный формат пароля',
   My_Lib_Validate_Password::INVALID_LENGTH => 'Длина пароля должна быть от 7 до 30ти символов',
   Zend_Captcha_Word::BAD_CAPTCHA => 'Вы указали не верные символы',
   Zend_Captcha_Word::MISSING_VALUE => 'Поле не может быть пустым',
   'userAgreement' => 'Регистрируясь вы должны согласится с правилами',    
);
```

**How to change validation error message for custom element?**

I'm trying to do it next way:

```
$validatorNotEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
$validatorNotEmpty->setMessages(array(
           Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY  => 'agreeRules'));
$userAgreement = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('userAgreement', array(
           'required'    => true,
           'label'       => 'Регистрируясь, вы должны согласиться с правилами:',            
           'validators'  => array($validatorNotEmpty),
       ));
```

And this way too:

```
$validatorNotEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
$validatorNotEmpty->setMessage(  'Регистрируясь вы должны согласится с правилами',
           Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY);
$userAgreement = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('userAgreement', array(
           'required'    => true,
           'label'       => 'Регистрируясь, вы должны согласиться с правилами:',            
           'validators'  => array($validatorNotEmpty),
       ));
```

Anyway I get message from translator file, not my custom written message text.

Comment: +1 for showing that you can use the static fields for error message translations. Hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
   $validatorNotEmpty->setMessages(array('agreeRules'));
```

it will overwrite all messages, but in IS_EMPTY case it actually is one message

you could try the other approach, translate by value

remove `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Поле не может быть пустым',`

```
$errors=array(
 //values
 'Value is required and cannot be empty' = > 'My translate',
 'agreeRules' => 'My rules'
);
```

then

```
$validatorNotEmpty->setMessages(array(
       Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY  => 'agreeRules'));
```

now your translation get the *text* and translates it,
else the translator uses 'notEmpty' (`Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY` is a string) for translation key and ignores the text 'agreeRules'

Answer (score 2):

you can write this after adding form element

```
$form->formElementName->setDisableTranslator(true);
```

it will disable translate for your element

Answer (score 1):

Please try below method to add element.

```
$this->addElement(

          'checkbox',

          'userAgreement',

           array(
    'label'      => 'Регистрируясь, вы должны согласиться с правилами:',
    'required'   => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array('NotEmpty', true, array( 'messages' => array( Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'agreeRules' ) ) ),
    )
));
```